# PHP MySQL used in library management system

Tags: javascript, php

I want to hide this button on click and also it restore s post values.and my condition is if-statement bid returned where should have place statement.

```html
<a rel="tooltip" title="Return" id="<?php echo $borrow_details_id; ?>" 
  href="#delete_book<?php echo $borrow_details_id; ?>" 
  data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success">
  <i class="icon-check icon-large"></i>Return
</a>
```

Comment: You mean JavaScript instead of Java?

Comment: Did you mean javascript instead of java? Javascript can handle DOM client-side and hide elements, java can't.

Comment: No just see that command nd tell me how include that statement to hide tat button.

Comment: PHP nd JavaScript